ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 100, 100, 3), found shape=(None, 100, 3)
I am trying to use a CNN keras model that I trained to classify images.
I am using model.predict(img) and I am getting an error with the expected shape.
It says the found shape=(None,100,3) and the expected shape=(None,100,100,3).
The CNN set up code is:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(image_size, image_size,dim3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

where image_size = 100 and dim3 = 3
img.shape returs TensorShape([100,100,3]).
Why is it expecting the first dimension to be none and how do I correctly use my trained CNN to classify and image?

It'd be easier if you had included the rest of the code as well, but my guess is the error is due to the fact that TensorFlow model accepts batches, you can just add a first dimension to you image array,
img= img[None, ...] # Create a batch

